# Where is `navigator.app` documentation?

Tags: cordova

I just see that `navigator.app` object in Cordova applications has some useful methods. But are they documented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this is a platform-specific API that is intentionally undocumented.

There was a ticket opened in beginning of 2012 and the conclusion was that as it was un-official and platform-specific, it would remain undoccumented : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-206

Comment: So... strange. There are some platform-specific things in docs, and a lot of people use `navigator.app.exitApp()`...

Comment: .. and so, what's the official way to exit the app? navigator.app.exitApp();