# Ionic 4 alternative for platform.registerBackButtonAction

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I looked around the new platform for the Ionic 4, it seems like the  `registerBackButtonAction` function was removed from it.

Are there any other alternatives to handle the Android hardware back button?

Comment: We got the workaround working, can you give it a try?https://stackoverflow.com/a/51729093/2422125

Comment: it is not the correct answer for my case.

Comment: Although this seems to be the right approach, it still does not close the app.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update:** This was fixed in [v4.0.0-beta.8 (dfac9dc)](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/commit/dfac9dc)

---

[Related: how to integrate hardware back button into ionic4 navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51729093/2422125)

---

This is tracked on [GitHub](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14803), in the [Ionic Forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/hardware-back-button-with-ionic-4/137905/22) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/manucorporat/status/1034962030636281857)
 
Until there is an official fix, you can use this workaround:

```ts
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
  // code that is executed when the user pressed the back button
})

// To prevent interference with ionic's own backbutton handling
// you can subscribe with a low priority instead
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
  // code that is executed when the user pressed the back button
  // and ionic doesn't already know what to do (close modals etc...)
})
```

<sup>Be aware that you need to save the result of `subscribe(...)`
if you ever want to unsubscribe from it again.</sup>

---

**Old answer:** (out of date as of April 2018)

`registerBackButtonAction` is [just a wrapper](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/156fdc35ed551977f5c015e408fd72e866fea703/ionic/platform/registry.ts#L177) for the [corresponding Cordova call](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html).

So you can just take your old call to `registerBackButtonAction`:

```ts
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => { 
  // code that is executed when the user pressed the back button
});
```

and replace it with:

```ts
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", () => { 
    // code that is executed when the user pressed the back button
  });
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177774/discussion-on-answer-by-fabian-n-ionic-4-alternative-for-platform-registerbackb).

Comment: nice one, i really looking for this everywhere and it seems this is the true workaround

Comment: @Xinez In case you are currently migrating and thinking about how to navigate back: since angular routing is now used its just `location.back()` from @angular/common **HOWEVER** that seems to break the back animation so stay with `navController.back()`

Comment: backButton.subscribe stopped working in ionic 4, don't understand why??

Comment: @AnkitMaheshwari which version? So much broke an was fixed again, I didn't try it for some time so no idea if it still works in 4.6.2

Comment: Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

i tried on

```
"@ionic/angular": "^4.7.0-dev.201907191806.32b736e",
"@ionic/core": "^4.7.0-dev.201907191806.32b736e",
```

it works!

ionic git commit https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/commit/978cc39009a9a0fb065540ce17e10c685b6c101a

Comment: yes, this is fixed in 4.7.2
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

In case of @ionic/vue you can put this (or something like this) in main.js

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core'

Plugins.App.addListener('backButton', function() {
  console.log(111);
  window.history.back();
});
```

No, no, `console.log(111);` is not mistake, it's part of solution :)

Comment: Please [edit] this to explain why the `console.log` call is so important.

Comment: This is the second guy I'm seeing put a `console.log` in an app and I'm still wondering what magic trick this is. How are you guys able to see that log when the app is running on a device?

Comment: Use chrome://inspect @DevYego. I think console.log delays the execution of the code and prevents a race condition, I had to use this approach in some Ionic code too. Usually a setTimeOut(..., 100) works too.