# What is the right way to use hardware back button in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular6, ionic4

i'm creating a ionic 4 app, and i want to use the device's hardware back-button to return at specific page

i'd checked in this page [Handling hardware back button in Ionic3 Vs Ionic4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700879/handling-hardware-back-button-in-ionic3-vs-ionic4) to create my code but it doesn't work

**detallesusuario.page.ts**

```
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, QueryList, ViewChildren}from '@angular/core';
    import { Platform, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-detallesusuario',
      templateUrl: './detallesusuario.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./detallesusuario.page.scss'],
      })
export class DetallesusuarioPage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(IonRouterOutlet) routerOutlets: QueryList<IonRouterOutlet> ;
  sub:Subscription
  constructor(private platform:Platform, private ruta:Router) { }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.backButtonEvent();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
  backButtonEvent() {
    let u=0;
    this.sub=this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
      this.routerOutlets.forEach(async(outlet: IonRouterOutlet) => {
                  console.log('paso');
                  await this.ruta.navigate(['menu/inicio/tabs/tab1']);

      });
    });
  }
}
```

When i deploy a app to a device, the button return to the previous page instead to go at the specific page

Answer (score 0):

The hardware back button handling code is found in:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/hardware-back-button.ts#L20

And that is exposed by the platform using `platform.backButton`:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/f44c17e03bfcd9f6f9375a19a8d06e9393124ac9/angular/src/providers/platform.ts#L21
- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/f44c17e03bfcd9f6f9375a19a8d06e9393124ac9/angular/src/providers/platform.ts#L48

It looks to me like you are using it correctly. I found [this article](https://medium.com/@aleksandarmitrev/ionic-hardware-back-button-nightmare-9f4af35cbfb0) showing the same technique, and also another forum post.

What looks strange to me is why you are getting `IonRouterOutlet` involved.

Have you tried it just using the `router` directly?

```
  backButtonEvent() {
    this.sub=this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
      console.log('paso');
      await this.ruta.navigate(['menu/inicio/tabs/tab1']);
    });
  }
```

Note: I'm assuming your choice of `ngAfterViewInit` make sense - I haven't double checked this.

However, you should also probably take a detailed look at this issue as it seems there are tons of problems with the hardware back button:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16611